# ERROR 1777 (HY000): Partition memsqldb:0 has no master instance

Tags: singlestore

I am using community edition of memsql. I got this error while i was running a query today. So i just restarted my cluster and got this error solved.

```
memsql-ops cluster-restart
```

But what happened and what should i do in future to avoid this error ?

**NOTE**

I donot want to buy the Enterprise edition.

**Question**

Is this problem of Availability ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because a leaf in your cluster has failed a health check heartbeat for some reason (loss of network connectivity, hardware failure, OS issue, machine overloaded, out of memory, etc.) and its partitions are no longer accessible to query.   MemSQL Community Edition only supports redundancy 1 so there are no other copies of the data on the failed leaf node in your cluster (thus the error about missing a partition of data - MemSQL can't complete a query that needs to read data on any partitions on the problem leaf).

Given that a restart repaired things, the most likely answer is that linux "out of memory" killed you: [MemSQL Linux OOM killer docs](http://docs.memsql.com/latest/concepts/memory_management/?highlight=maximum_memory#linux-out-of-memory-behavior)

You can also check the tracelog on the leaf that ran into issues to see if there is any clue there about what happened (It's usually at /var/lib/memsql/leaf_3306/tracelogs/memsql.log)

-Adam

Comment: Good to see memsql core people answering questiosn :)

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when experimenting with performance.

VM had 24 CPUs and 25 nodes: 1 Master Agg, 24 Leaf nodes
Reduced VM to 4 CPUs and restarted cluster.

All the leaves did not recover.
All except 4 recovered in < 5 minutes.
20 minutes later, 4 leaf nodes still were not connected.

From MySQL/MemSQL prompt:

```
use db;
show partitions;
```

I notice some partitions with ordinal from 0-71 for me have null instead Host, Port, Role defined for a given partition.

In memsql ops UI http://server:9000 > Settings > Config > Manual Cluster Control I checked "ENABLE MANUAL CONTROL" while I tried to run various commands with no real benefit.

Then 15 minutes later, I unchecked the box, Memsql-ops tried attaching all the leaf nodes again and was finally successful.

Perhaps a cluster restart would have done the same thing.

Comment: Yes You are right , i could sense that because when we restart a cluster all nodes try to recover their data and thus the problem solves

Answer (score 2):

I too have faced this error, that was because some of the slave ordinals had no corresponding masters. My error message looked like:

```
ERROR 1772 (HY000) at line 1: Leaf Error (10.0.0.112:3306): Partition database `<db_name>_0` can't be promoted to master because it is provisioning replication
```

My `memsql> SHOW PARTITIONS;` command returned the following.

[image]

So what approach I followed was to remove each of such cases (where the role was either Slave or NULL).

`DROP PARTITION <db_name>:4 ON "10.0.0.193":3306;`
..
`DROP PARTITION <db_name>:46 ON "10.0.0.193":3306;`

And then created a new partition with each of the dropped partition.

`CREATE PARTITION <db_name>:4 ON "10.0.0.193":3306;`
..
`CREATE PARTITION <db_name>:46 ON "10.0.0.193":3306;`

And this was the result of `memsql> SHOW PARTITIONS;` after that.

[image]

You can refer to the MemSQL Documentation regarding partitions, [here](https://docs.memsql.com/concepts/v6.7/partitions/) if the above steps doesn't seem to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting the same problem. Using the following command in the master node, solved the problem:

```
REBALANCE PARTITIONS ON db_name
```

Optionally you can force it using `FORCE`:

```
REBALANCE PARTITIONS ON db_name FORCE
```

And to see the list of operations when rebalancing is going to execute, use above command with `EXPLAIN`:

```
 EXPLAIN REBALANCE PARTITIONS ON db_name [FORCE]
```